# ¿Qué es el "pésame" exactamente?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, etimología, expresiones

Cuando alguien ha muerto, en castellano *damos el pésame* a las personas próximas a quien se fue. Esto es, ofrecemos nuestro afecto, cariño y apoyo en esos momentos de pena y dolor.

El DRAE lo define como:

> [**pésame**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Sm6AMQp)
>   1. m. Expresión con que se hace saber a alguien el sentimiento que se tiene de su pena o aflicción.

Es decir, una palabra sola constituye de por sí una expresión. En particular, se conjuga en modo reflexivo el verbo [*pesar*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SmGC3aC%7CSmGsWXw) (*Dicho de la razón o el motivo de algo: Hacer fuerza en el ánimo* / *Sentimiento o dolor interior que molesta y fatiga el ánimo*).

Por tanto, parece como que venga de la frase completa:

> Me pesa tu dolor tanto como a ti; aquí tienes mi apoyo.

Pero tengo curiosidad por saber si este es su origen exacto y en qué punto se acortó tanto para pasar a contener todo el significado de la frase en una sola palabra. ¿Alguien lo conoce?

Comment: @diego acaso sabías que uno de mis fastídiames son los pésames inauténticos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La forma "pésame" se lleva usando desde los orígenes del lenguaje:

> *—Reína doña Tacriça, yo rey Darcón vi vuestra carta, e pésame mucho de lo que me embiastes dezir que érades dolient.*
>
> Alfonso X, "General Estoria. Primera parte", c 1275 (España).

Un texto un poco más moderno:

> *Y pésame mucho que tan grave crimen los infantes de Carrión ayan cometido, y por ende tengo por bien de los mandar emplazar que de oy en tres meses vengan ante mí.*
>
> Anónimo, "Corónica del Çid Ruy Díaz", 1498 (España).

Un siglo más tarde aún se seguía usando:

> *—Yo creí que en la Corte os hubieran hecho una estatua, como a hombre famoso, y pésame de veros flaco y pobre.*
>
> Juan Rufo, "Las seiscientas apotegmas", 1596 (España)

Como ves, durante todo el siglo XVI aún se usa la forma *pésame* como verbo para indicar cualquier tipo de pesar que le aflige a uno. No es de extrañar que en ese mismo siglo aparezcan los primeros casos de *pésame* como sustantivo, expresando con el mismo cualquier frase que comience por dicha palabra para indicar una aflicción:

> *Instrucción del Rey Católico á su capellán Juan de Aponte, fraile de la Orden de Santiago, para dar el pésame á la Duquesa de Sesa y de Terranova y á su hija por la muerte del Gran capitán.*
>
> Anónimo, "Documentos relativos al Gran Capitán [Cartas del Gran Capitán]", c 1515 (España).
>
> ---
>
> *Finalmente digo que muchos se dan el parabién de alguna buena fortuna que querrían más darse el pésame de alguna gran desgracia.*
>
> Fray Antonio de Guevara, "Menosprecio de corte y alabanza de aldea", 1539 (España).

Como ves, la forma por aquel entonces ya era *dar el pésame*. La primera aparición de *pésame* como sustantivo en un diccionario es en el español-francés de Oudin de 1607:

[image: Dar el pésame]

Verás que distingue entre "el pésame" y la forma verbal "pésame".