# ¿Cómo se da el pésame?

Tags: expresiones, solicitud-de-modismo

Esta pregunta se inspiró por esta otra pregunta acerca del pésame: [¿Qué es el "pésame" exactamente?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/20163/9385)

Si voy al velorio para dar el pésame al pariente del difunto, ¿qué mero puedo / debo decir?  (En inglés hay una frase básica: *I'm sorry for your loss.*)

---

It's good to learn the formulas for speaking with an acquaintance, but it would also be helpful to get some examples of something one might say to a closer friend or relative.  I realize one might make some extended remarks in some situations, and I'm not asking that people pour their heart out here, but it would still be helpful to get some examples that would get one started.  One answer says that the better you know the person, the less you say.  I wonder if that's a general approach that most people take.

Answer (score 3):

La fórmula estándar en España **cuando no hay una relación estrecha con el fallecido o su familia** es:

> Le acompaño en el sentimiento

Según [**Wikipedia**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%A9same) (negritas mías)

> La fórmula más común es "**Te acompaño en el sentimiento**" pero también se utilizan otras del tipo "**Lamento mucho el fallecimiento de...**", "**He sentido mucho la pérdida de...**" o "**Mi más sentido pésame**".

Answer (score 2):

La frase que todo mundo usa en México es: "Mi más sentido pésame" y usualmente es seguida por "Estamos con ustedes en su dolor".

Answer (score 2):

Imagino que esta pregunta va a tener variaciones regionales. Por mi parte, y hablando desde el español de España, las expresiones con *pésame* ("mi más sincero pésame" y similares) me parecen distantes y las reservo para cuando no conozco bien al fallecido o a la persona a la que me dirijo. Si esta es una **persona que conozco y con la que tengo confianza**, en las ocasiones en las que me ha tocado pasar por esto lo que suelo decir es simplemente:

> Lo siento mucho.

Otra variante puede ser:

> Siento mucho lo de tu `<parentesco del fallecido>`.

Comment: @walen en abosluto, me parece muy correcta la edición, sobre todo cuando nuestro amigo Potter-Pirbright ha puesto [una opción mucho más formal](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/30560/12637).

Answer (score 1):

A las respuestas existentes voy a añadir otra fórmula que es útil conocer:

> Mis más sinceras **condolencias** por la pérdida.

Por si no conocías ese palabra [condolencia](https://dle.rae.es/?id=AC9oW7V) viene a ser el *commiseration* en inglés.

> 1. f. Participación en el pesar ajeno.
> 2. f. pésame.

Comment: Gracias, Diego.  También hay: *condolences*.